# punctuation marks - importance and examples

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I wonder whether there are such cases in English when punctuation marks (commas, semicolons and so on) can change the meaning of the sentence completely?

For example, in Russian it happens very often, and it is so interesting if the English language has the same issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it happens to be in many languages as well as in English.

For example:

> Let's eat grandma.

Vs.

> Let's eat, grandma.

[image]

For more examples - see here:
[10 Hilarious Examples Of How Punctuation Makes A Big Difference.](https://digitalsynopsis.com/tools/punctuation-marks-importance-rules-usage/)